# Adding data to nested model rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails and can't figure out how to do this. I have implemented a user log in system using devise and I am trying to let a user create multiple "listings". Sort of like a craigslist type site. I can populate the database from the rails console but I cant figure out how to put it on the site.

I have the following models:

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

  #add validations

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb (used devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I am trying to create a page which allows a user to create a new listing. I am not exactly sure how to go about doing this. This is what I have currently:

listings_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
      flash[:success] = "Success"
      redirect_to @listing
    else
     render 'new'
    end
  end

private

  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:id, :user_id, :title, :general_info)
  end

end
```

models/views/listings/new.html.erb

```
<h1> POST A NEW LISTING </h>

    <%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
      Title: <%= f.text_field :title %> <br />
      General Info: <%= f.text_field :general_info %> <br />

      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Ive been working on this for quite a while with no luck getting the database to populate. Currently the form once submits hits the "else" in def create and just renders the same page.

Here is the log output when I run this:

```
Started POST "/listings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-04 17:37:53 -0600
Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mlyDb24OMQkniOCFQ1JTvzxjplHk7kMgzEBEFBH8hGw=", "listing"=>{"title"=>"title should go here", "general_info"=>"hope this works"}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered listings/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 10.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: I hope it's not because of `:tile` in your `listing_params` method.  Is that a typo or you haven't noticed that?  Also do you see any errors in your log file?

Comment: Good catch, I somehow missed that. That however was not the problem and it wasn't even giving an error. I posted the log output in the OP now.

Comment: Are you using devise 3.0.0.rc?

Comment: yes i am using 3.0.0rc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following got this to work for anyone who comes across this problem:

In routes.db I put the listings in a block:

```
 resources :users do
      resource :listings
  end
```

For the new/show/create methods I made sure to search for the user first (note since I am using devise the current_user.id)

```
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @listing = @user.listings.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @listing = @user.listings.build(listing_params)

    if @listing.save
      flash[:success] = "Success"
      redirect_to root_path 
    else
     render :action => 'new'
    end

  end
```

then finally, changed the form_for  in new.html.erb to this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @listing] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  ...

  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I did what you suggested but still, when i'm accessing the url listings/1/edit the Edit form still pops up :(

Comment: I'm getting a problem if i alter the routes file as you said. Could you post your Full routes file ?